# C++ compare strings up to "%" char

Tags: c++, boost, stl, string-comparison

I would like to implement a string comparison in C++ comparing strings up to a "%" sign.

I could do it like this:

```
std::equal(str1.begin(), 
           std::find(str1.begin(), str1.end(), L'%'),
           str2.begin());
```

Since I'm doing this in a loop over many strings, I wonder if there is a method without two distinct string traversals for `find` and `equal` (maybe with a predicate that can abort the comparison at any point). Boost is ok.

Comment: Could you give some examples of the strings you are comparing? There's at least 3 differing interpretations of your input strings floating about.

Comment: "The current volume is: \"%1\"" vs. "The current volume is: \"C:\""

Comment: Is `str1` always going to contain `%` or can `str2` have it but not `str1`?

Comment: @greatwolf In my case, only `str1` will (maybe) contain a `%` of interest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch). 
The following code will run with C++14 (it requires the template overload with two iterator pairs), but it works quite similar in C++11 (or 03, without lambdas though):

```
auto iters = std::mismatch( str1.begin(), str1.end(), str2.begin(), str2.end(), 
                     [] (char lhs, char rhs) {return lhs != '%' && lhs == rhs;});


if (iters.first  == str1.end()
 || iters.second == str2.end()
 || *iters.first == '%')
    // Success […]
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5fa1c7b75bd3a96).

Comment: Nice nice nice! And std::mismatch is in C++03 which is a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hackish way of doing it:

```
auto it = std::find_if(
  str1.begin(), str1.end(),
  [&str2](const char &c) {
    return c == '%' || str2[&c - &str1[0]] != c
  }
);
bool equal = (it == str1.end() || *it == '%');
```

The idea is to create a predicate "character is the same as in the other string and not a `'%'`."

It relies on `str2` being long enough, but so does the code in the question.